# Setting focus on an html element in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set the focus on a text input element using

```
document.getElementById( 'id' ).focus()
```

This works in Firefox 3, but does not work in Internet Explorer 8.

What is the correct way to set focus on an HTML element in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't another problem with your code?  I don't have an IE8 to test with, but this self-contained example works perfectly in IE7 - perhaps you could try it in IE8?

```
<html><body>
<form><input type='text' id='bim'></form>
<script>document.getElementById('bim').focus()</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely correct.  I had an unrelated bug in my code that prevented it from working in IE.

Comment: Blast from the past .. setting `value='wagga'` in the above example disproves that it works. .focus() will select the value in Chrome but not in IE8. Any advice in this matter?

Comment: My bad, I think .. `.select()` will select the value in both Chrome and IE8, `.focus()` will do two different things in the two browsers. Sorry.